# 3G/4G device that's less likely to be backdoored

Tags: wifi

I can't use wifi at the moment so my only option is some sort of cellular connection (either through USB modem or mifi hotspot). I have been looking at devices but most seem to be Chinese companies that have had backdoor claims against them (ZTE, Huawei). Aside from finding wifi, what could I do? I'm in Europe.

Comment: Put on your tinfoil hat!

Comment: I thought this was a serious forum for adult discussion. Could you actually be helpful?

Comment: I think that you overestimate the likelihood that there's a backdoor in these devices that is going to somehow hurt your security. Even if there is, you are probably safe if you use a VPN service. Also, this question may be closed as hardware recommendation are off-topic per the help section. There is a sister site that is meant specifically for [hardware recommendations](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/) that may be more appropriate.